# ¿Cómo cambiar de ruta en laravel "home", despues de logearse el usuario?

Tags: laravel

Una vez que el usuario se logea el sistema envía al usuario a la ruta home, necesito cambiar esa ruta, he intentado con varias opciones y no he podido aún, necesito envíar unos datos de una consulta a la base de datos a esa ruta.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Puedes poner codigo de lo que haz intentado? capturas de errores?

Comment: Lo quieres hacer desde el mismo controller auth o por otra via??

Comment: Gracias a todos, ya lo resolví abajo está descrito el problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desde

`\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php`

esta la variable que redirecciona despues de hacer **login** `protected $redirectTo = '/home';` Ahi cambias la **ruta** `/home` por la que desees.

Comment: Gracias, lo intenté por allí el problema era una ruta resource, la cambié y le dí un nombre y funcionó